# Cannot install 64-bit version of Visio due to Microsoft Office Single Image 2010

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, microsoft-office-2010

I tried to install Visio on Windows 7, but I received the below error message.

> You cannot install the 64-bit version of Office 2010 because you have
>   32-bit Office products installed. These 32-bit products are not
>   supported with 64-bit installations:
>
> ```
>              Microsoft Office Single Image 2010
> ```
>
> If you want to install 64-bit Office 2010, you must uninstall all
>   32-bit Office products first, and then run setup.exe in the x64
>   folder. If you want to install 32-bit Office 2010, close this Setup
>   program, and then either go to the x86 folder at the root of your CD
>   or DVD and run setup.exe, or get the 32-bit Office 2010 from the same
>   place you purchased 64-bit Office 2010.

I cannot find Microsoft Office Single Image 2010 in the programs list, so I tried to use Microsoft's [Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) to remove the software, but this doesn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Read and follow any possible solutions within the following discussion http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/need-to-uninstall-ms-office-single-image-2010-32/69962e2c-ba90-49d5-934f-3c6d50b51e8c you should also follow the following knowlege question on Microsoft's own website http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218

Comment: @Ramhound As indicated in the question, I already tried to use Fix It (which is the suggested resolution in both the above links).

Comment: I linked to a different one. If that fails use the discontinued tool.  You should use `Uninstall Microsoft Office 2010 suites with Microsoft Fix it` not the other `Fixit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some helpful links here:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/need-to-uninstall-ms-office-single-image-2010-32/69962e2c-ba90-49d5-934f-3c6d50b51e8c
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218

The `Uninstall Microsoft Office 2010 suites with Microsoft Fix it` helped to resolve this issue.